# Square Grid with Gaps in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the twitter bootstrap grid system for a responsive website. Most of my markup works just fine, but I've one nasty problem, which makes me mad.

I need the following markup result: [image]

As you can see, there are three different types of boxes.

- A black square (with a background-image)
- A red square with the size of four black squares (with a red background and text in it)
- A gray rectangle with the width of three black squares and the height of two black squares (with text in it)

I've prepared a fiddle to let you see what my current state is: http://www.bootply.com/c8T4ofjA54

I have problems to get the correct height of the boxes and the margin in between.

Hope that somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: In my experience, bad things happen if you start messing up with col padding / margin. Unless you are using less / sass and you do it in the variables file.

Comment: In the main project I'm using less with variables. So there is not that mess.

Comment: Well then why don't you modify the margin between cols. If you can solve that you can structure the whole thing with rows and cols. For example https://plnkr.co/edit/hzPkTWRacfwzCSahCm3c?p=preview

Comment: But we have the problem to let the squares be squares in a responsive way. So we can't use fixed heightsif we work with percentage width.